# barcode module in titanium for android not working

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to integrate module for android for implementing barcode scanner.
I saw planning to use "ti.barcode" or "Acktie-Mobile-Android-Barcode",
but for both my application crashes when i try to execute the code for calling scan method.

I am testing on `android 6.0.1 nexus 6` with `titanium 5.1.2` with most latest updated version of same.

for `ti.barcode` i have used latest 2.3.5 and for "Acktie-Mobile-Android-Barcode" I have used 1.8, and even `ti.redlaser 1.1.2` also but all are failing work.

Everytime app crashes.

I have checked the `gitHub` repo for all modules for this functionality.
all seems to be 3+yrs old. Nothing updated.

I am using the same source code from the "example" directory of module.

Which module should I use to scan barcode.?

Answer (score 0):

The Scandit barcode reader works for us in Android. While it's not free, it is well supported and kept up-to-date.